# recursively remove "[" and "]" pattern in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was trying to remove the "["or "]" pattern present in a string.

```
var str = "abc<1<2<>3>4>def";

while (str != (str = str.replace(/<[^<>]*>/g, "")));
```

using the above code which is removing "<" "<>" ">" pattern when i try to replace this with my operators it does'nt work .

any ways can any one provide me any regex or small one liner to replace all the operator present.

```
For ex a= [1[2]3][4
should be after removing 1234
 or
a =1[2]3]
should be after removing 123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var str = "abc[1[2[]3]4]def".replace(/\[|\]/g, "");
```

Your while condition is not required here as the regex will remove all instances of `[` and `]` it finds due to the `g` global parameter.

Comment: OP's while condition removes the enclosing text between the `[]` or `<>` (replacing innermost brackets first and outermost brackets last), it does not just remove the brackets. If the `<>` in that while loop are replaced  properly with `[]` then `"abc[1[2[]3]4]def"` becomes `abcdef` and not `abc1234def`.

Answer (score 1):

What about just

```
s = "[1[2]3][4"
s = s.replace(/[[\]]/g, "")
```

gives you the output

```
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
var str = "abc[1[2[]3]4]def";
while (str != (str = str.replace(/\[[^\[\]]*\]/g, "")));
```

`str` becomes `abcdef` recursively removing all the enclosed text between `[]`. This would work only if the square brackets are balanced.

You can use this regex if you need to remove all the brackets

```
var str = str.replace(/]|\[/g, "");
```